# Show every dilation is a non-constant linear function.

Tags: proof-writing, euclidean-geometry

A dilation of reals is a function $f:\Re \mapsto \Re$ such that for some constant $c\neq0$ one has $|f(x)-f(y)|=c\ast|x-y|$ for all $x,y\in\Re$.

1. Show that every non-constant linear function is a dilation.
2. Show that every dilation is a non-constant linear function.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem so far? What have you tried?

Comment: We do not have a formal textbook for the class I am taking and in our lecture notes there is no reference to dilation nor to non-constant linear functions.  I am not sure where to start to even begin this problem; I do see your hints below, but they are no help since I have no actual reference point.  If you can give me a website or just the first couple of lines, I might be able to muddle through this...Thanks, and sorry it took so long to get back to you, I was double checking the notes.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include some definitions.  See if that's enough to get you started.  If you're still stuck, I'll put some more down there.

Comment: It seems I've made a mistake in my interpretation of the question. I'll delete my question for now, and undelete it once I've updated it to be correct.

Comment: In particular, it seems that a "linear function" means a function of the form $f(x) = ax + b$ for $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: I believe I have done the proof correctly, see my answer below...

Answer (score 2):

A dilation of reals is a function $f:R\to R$ such that for some constant $c\ne 0$ one has

$$|f(x)-f(y)|=c\cdot |x-y|$$

for all $x,y\in R$.

$Definition:$ A linear function is one where changing the input by any quantity changes the output by that quantity multiplied by a fixed number. Also, if a function is non-constant then, it has an end.

1. Show that every non-constant linear function is a dilation.

Using the definition of a linear function as described above, we can make a formula as shown: $f(x)=c\cdot x$

So if we have two functions that are non-constant [$f(x)$ and $f(y)$], $f(x)=c\cdot x$ and $f(y)=c\cdot y$.
If we subtract the two functions it gives us a new non-constant linear function:
$$f(x,y) = |f(x)-f(y)|=|c\cdot x| - |c\cdot y|$$

This can be reduced to the formula: 
$$f(x,y) = |f(x)-f(y)|=c\cdot |x-y|$$
which is the formula of a dilation of reals. This shows us that every non constant linear function is a dilation.

1. Show that every dilation is a non-constant linear function.

Now this can be reversed to show that every dilation is a non-constant linear function.
The formula of a dilation is shown as:

$$f(x,y) = |f(x)-f(y)|=c\cdot |x-y|$$

If you distribute the c it gives us the formula: 
$$f(x,y) = |f(x)-f(y)|=|c\cdot x| - |c\cdot y|$$

which is a non-constant linear function because it is the subtraction of two other non-constant linear functions.
Which has shown us that every dilation is a non-constant linear function.